# Error: listen EADDRINUSE when use (node --harmony debug.js) too many times

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using total.js which is a MVC framework for nodejs, following the total's tutorial, I use command `node --harmony debug.js` to start a web server listening port *8000*.

```
------------> PID: 559
====================================================
PID          : 560
node.js      : v0.12.6
total.js     : v1.9.0
====================================================
Name         : total.js
Version      : 1.01
Author       : You company name
Date         : 2015-08-20 11:13:26
Mode         : debug
====================================================

http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

I use the command many times when I modify files, But I close previous one with `ctrl+c` everytime. It works in the first several times, but after that I get this:

```
{ [Error: listen EADDRINUSE] code: 'EADDRINUSE', errno: 'EADDRINUSE', syscall: 'listen' }

The IP address and the PORT is already in use.
You must change the PORT's number or IP address.
```

**Trial**

I tried many ways but it didn't work.

1. Restart my Mac Pro.
2. Find the process which is listening port 8000.

   I use many command like ps,netstat,lsof and so on. But I couldn't find anything about port 8000 or 80. I also use `killall node` to kill anything about node, but it says:

   > No matching processes belonging to you were found
3. Kill zombie process.

   I think maybe it's a zombie process which stops me.But I didn't find anything about zombie.

Shall I reinstall node?I think it's a problem of node instead of total.js. I don't know how to solve this problem.Could anyone do me a favour?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

for running app in port 80 on your Mac, you must use `sudo node`

Comment: Thanks. But I get the same result when I add `sudo`.I think it's not about permission.